# Iphone MapKit displaying route

Tags: xcode, ios4, mapkit, core-location

I would like to show the route between 2 locations, from the users current location to a certain point on the map. I have seen this done in a couple of applications like layar.
http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/layar-reality-browser/id334404207

Can someone give me pointers on how to achieve this on iphone sdk 4

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using kishikawakatsumi's [code on github](https://github.com/kishikawakatsumi/MapKit-Route-Directions).

Looks like he provides a wrapper around the Google Maps routing API which will give you the route, and then some custom MKAnnotations to handle drawing those routes in MapKit.